# Can't open ddms

Tags: android, linux

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS to build android using command line. However after I open emulator, trying to open ddms. I got the following error message

> 09:36:10 E/ddms: shutting down due to uncaught exception 09:36:10
>   E/ddms: org/eclipse/jface/util/IPropertyChangeListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/jface/util/IPropertyChangeListener    at
>   com.android.ddms.Main.main(Main.java:74) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.jface.util.IPropertyChangeListener    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 1 more

It seems that there is a class not being found. But I am not sure what exactly it means.
After searching, I found it may be wrong ANDROID_SWT. However after I check, there still exist the same problem.

Any idea can help! Thx!